# Структура данных в задаче "Волчий остров"

Tags: c, структуры-данных

Как бы Вы организовали данные в такой задаче? Программирую я на C, если это вдруг важно.

Волчий остров размером 20х20 заселен дикими кроликами, волками и волчицами. Имеется по нескольку представителей каждого вида. Кролики довольно глупы: в каждый момент времени они с одинаковой вероятностью 1/9 передвигаются в один из восьми соседних квадратов (за исключением участков, ограниченных береговой линией) или просто сидят неподвижно. Каждый кролик с вероятностью 0,2 превращается в двух кроликов. Каждая волчица передвигается случайным образом, пока в одном из соседних восьми квадратов не окажется кролик, за которым она охотится. Если волчица и кролик оказываются в одном квадрате, волчица съедает кролика и получает одно очко. В противном случае она теряет 0,1 очка. Волки и волчицы с нулевым количеством очков умирают.

В начальный момент времени все волки и волчицы имеют 1 очко. Волк ведет себя подобно волчице до тех пор, пока в соседних квадратах не исчезнут все кролики; тогда, если волчица находится в одном из восьми близлежащих квадратов, волк гонится за ней. Если волк и волчица окажутся в одном квадрате и там нет кролика, которого нужно съесть, они производят потомство случайного пола.

Запрограммировать предполагаемую экологическую модель и понаблюдать за изменением популяции в течение некоторого периода времени.

Я рассматривал несколько вариантов: список зверей, при этом элемент "зверь" хранит собственные координаты. Но тогда поиск "соседей" осложняется. Можно сделать массив списков. В каждом таком списке только те звери, которые "живут" в соответствующем месте карты. Уже лучше. Была даже мысль организовать данные так: в каждой ячейке массива структура (одна, не список), а внутри число (количество зайцев) и два массива из 10 элементов каждый. В каждой ячейке массива - количество волков/волчиц, имеющих соответствующее здоровье (0.1 очка, 0.2 очка и т.д.) Это идеальный вариант, но он предполагает, что больше 1 очка у волка не может быть, а в условии задачи об этом прямо не говорится. Хотя это логично, ведь нельзя же съесть тонну еды, чтобы потом не есть год.

Comment: Как всегда задача сформулирована неполно. 

Соверенно не определен порядок действий на каждом шаге. Что происходит в начале, перемещение или поедание и размножение. Или сначала происходят *все перемещения*, а потом анализ ситуации в каждой клетке и действия?

--

По поводу структур данных. Для начала я бы попробовал использовать список зверей (в предположении, что ходы волков и зайцев независимы друг от друга) и массив структур (20х20) с описанием ситуации в каждой клетке (в т.ч. списки кроликов и волков в ней (ссылки на элементы общего списка зверей)).

--

Для начала, какие-то такие мысли.

Comment: мое предложение - в массиве 20 на 20 храниться структура


    struct cell {
      int rabbit; // кол-во зайцев
      int* wolfs; // очки волков
      int* she_wolfs;// очки волчиц
    }

очки предлагаю хранить умноженными на 10 во избежания проблем вещественным сравнением.

Но есть одна проблема с задачей в целом. Это порядок ходов. Если в двух соседних клетках находятся заяц и волк, и первый ходит заяц, то волк может остаться голодным. Если же первый ходит волк - он то зайца может скушать. Поэтому, я предлагаю, что вначале ходят все зайцы, потом все волки - по очереди.

Comment: Согласен, что с условиями задачи больше вопросов, чем условий для программирования.

Что должен делать волк, если в его клетку пришел заяц? Сначала съесть его и идти в соседнюю клетку (а если там еще заяц, то его тоже есть?) или наоборот, или что?

Comment: У меня было немного свободного времени, я реализовал это следующим образом: сначала абсолютно все делают движение. Потом абсолютно все выполняют действия.

При этом у всех животных есть параметр "инициатива". При старте он 6+/-2 у всех (случайное значение в диапазоне). Затем у дочернего животного этот статус равен статусу родителя +/-2 (таким образом со временем и волки, и зайцы должны становиться инициативнее, т.к. чаще размножаться будут более инициативные).

Comment: Расчет движения идет так: сначала двигаются те, у кого инициатива 1, потом те, у кого 2 и т.п.. Соответственно, чем выше инициатива у волка, тем выше шанс, что кролик, к которому он пойдет, уже ходил, а значит уже не убежит и волк его съест.

Надо отметить, что с указанными условиями в какой-то момент количество кроликов начинает уходить в бесконечность и волки не могут их догнать. Для балансирования этого я думаю о создании питания для кроликов в виде случайно появляющегося всегда одинакового количества капусты в регионах.

Comment: Если же ограничить кроликов сверху (я добавлял им запрет размножаться, если в клетке уже более 10ти кроликов), то в тот момент, когда волки способны съесть больше кроликов, чем рождается, и численность последних начинает идти на убыль, волки слишком медленно умирают, поэтому успевают сожрать абсолютно всех))
Даже с учетом того, что я добавил ограничение на рождение, рожать может только самка сытая не менее чем на 5 пунктов, новорожденные сыты на 5 пунктов и съеденный кролик дает +8, все равно волки мрут слишком медленно.

Comment: Интересно.

А что получается если детерминировано сначала ходят все зайцы, потом (на основе уже их нового положения) все волки (т.е. если заяц зашел к волку, то волк не ходит), потом волки жрут (1 волк не более 1 зайца за раз, именно на этом такте меняются очки волка и он может умереть), потом оставшиеся зайцы размножаются, потом размножаются волки.

Опять же можно поиграть с сытостью волка. Например, если у него более 1  очка, то он на этом ходу не ест (т.о. максимум очков у волка = 2).

Какая получится динамика?

--

Кстати, оформите все это (комментарии) в виде ответа и опишите структуры.

Comment: @VadimTukaev, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: @avp интересная особенность: если зайцы ходят первыми, то пока волков мало (10 самцов и 10 самок) и мало зайцев (70), волки питаются хуже. Скорее всего, это связано с тем, что у зайца выше вероятность отбежать от волка, чем подбежать к нему, в результате даже если волк и заяц находятся рядом, заяц первый делает ход, отбегая, а волк после этого вообще не знает, куда двигаться, и случайно двигается тоже от зайца.

Answer (score 3):

С точки зрения ООП (Java) в этой игре есть 5 классов:

1. Игровая карта класс `Environment` - класс или статический или в виде `Singleton`
2. Животное - абстрактный класс `Animal`
3. Волк - класс `Wolf extends Animal`
4. Волчица - класс `Wolfess extends Wolf`
5. Кролик - класс `Rabbit extends Animal`

При этом класс `Animal` содержит текущие координаты и имеет 3 абстрактных метода:

1. `doStep()` - шаг, логика которого отличается у волков и кроликов
2. `doBirth()` - рождение, пустой у волков, непустой у волчиц и кроликов
3. `doEat()` - поедание - непустой у волков и волчиц и пустой у кроликов

Класс `Environment` кроме игрового поля содержит в себе список животных - типа `List<Animal>`, который добавляется/убавляется при отработке методов `doBirth()` и `doEat()`

Собсно игровой ход: получаем объект `Environment` берем список животных и по каждому из них делаем `doStep()`

Как то так.

Comment: Мне кажется, что правильно будет делать `do_step()` на базе *не текущего, а начального* (перед первым `do_step()`) состояния карты.

После этого для всех занятых клеток по очереди сначала `do_eat()`, а потом `do_birth()`.

Comment: ну это уже детали реализации

Answer (score 3):

Я писал на С++, но общий принцип следующий.

1. Объект Region - содержит в себе перечень животных.
2. Объект Map - содержит в себе перечень регионов и их координаты.
3. Объект MapControl - по-сути, объект, управляющий игрой. Имеет набор методов, каждый из которых на вход ждет ссылку на карту. Методы: вывести состояние карты и животных на экран, вывести статистику (в моем случае по мутациям и по количеству живых на карте), задать стартовое состояние карты (случайная расстановка зайцев и волков), MoveAll (это сдвиг всех монстров на карте) и ActAll (это выполнение всех действий всех монстров на карте).
4. Объект Action с одним абстрактным методом Do, принимающим на вход координаты, животное и карту. Объект, который имеет право изменять состояние животных и карты.
5. Объекты, наследники от Action, это 3 варианта движения для волков (с разной логикой), питание для волков, размножение для зайцев, размножение для волков, смерть для волков.
6. Иерархия классов животных, как у Barmaley: Animal с двумя абстрактными методами, один возвозвращает Action движения животного, другой возвращает массив указателей на все Action's животного, которые должны быть выполнены на этапе ActAll.
7. Объект Rabbit : public Animal с реализацией методов, возвращающих относящиеся к нему Actions, и аналогично два объекта Wolf и Wolfess.

Поскольку я ввел понятие инициативы, и выполнение Move происходит в очередности ее роста (чем меньше инициатива, тем раньше сдвиг), при этом при размножении заяц имеет инициативу родителя +/-2, волк = (инициативу папы * 3 + инициативу мамы * 1)/4 +/- 4, волчица просто (инициативу папы * 3 + инициативу мамы * 1)/4. Таким образом, волчицы не мутируют, но наследуют мутацию отца.

Кроме того, выживаемость волков сильно возросла, когда я добавил условие, что если волк сыт более чем на 6, то сначала он ищет волчицу, а потом еду.

При стартовых 170ти зайцах и 20-20 волков, есть несколько этапов развития:

1. популяция зайцев медленно растет к 600-700, популяция волков до 150-200 каждого пола.
2. популяция зайцев начинает резко падать до 20-40, волки тоже переходят свой максимум и их в районе 100-150 каждого пола.
3. популяция зайцев начинает потихоньку расти, до 70-80, волки к этому моменту вымирают.

Так вот, ожидаемо, что инициатива зайцев будет все время увеличиваться. И к третьему этапу вместо стартовых средних 5,5, зайцы имеют ~9,5 в среднем. Но что удивительно - инициатива волков падает. И когда их остается несколько десятков, их средняя инициатива колеблется в районе 3-4.
Я предполагаю, что высокая инициатива, хоть и хорошо сказывается на охоте, плохо сказывается на спаривании (инициатива самок должна быть маленькой), поэтому в итоге инициатива лучшего волка бывает ниже инициативы худшего зайца. 
Кроме того, тот, кто последним пришел в регион (с более высокой инициативой), оказывается в конце списка животных, и если там уже несколько волков, ему может не хватить зайцев.

Такие вот интересные результаты :)

Comment: Здорово!

А если убрать инициативу (максимально приблизить правила к описанным ТС), то какова динамика?

Comment: Если убрать мутацию и просто поставить зайцам более низкую инициативу (сначала ходят все зайцы, потом все волки), то если при старте волков достаточно мало, количество зайцев уходит под 100 000, пока волки начнут уменьшать их количество (зайцы плодятся с шансом 0,2, волки с шансом 0,5 в тот момент, когда в каждой клетке есть по самцу и самке, поэтому догоняют).
Затем волки быстро съедают всех зайцев, и затем мрут с голоду )

Comment: Интересно, что когда я сделал обработку списка животных с конца (чтобы первыми если дети и пришедшие последними, т.е. более инициативные волки), то средняя инициатива волков начала расти, и можно наблюдать забавную гонку инициатив волков и зайцев :)

Comment: Добавил новый тип регионов - непроходимые, в среднем четверть всех - такие. Динамика совершенно иная. За счет кластеризации карты, выживаемость резко повышена. Волки домутировали до 20х инициатив, причем, не в погоне за зайцами, а в борьбе между собой: у кого выше, тот первый кушает, а вот зайцы как будто не имеют стимула к мутации и вертятся вокруг 5,5, но теперь все живы и через 100 итераций. Жизнь, блин =)

Comment: Точно. 

А Вы знаете такую "игру" -- [Conway's Game of Life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life)?

И в xscreensaver-е есть заставка на ее основе -- CloudLife - очень интересно наблюдать.